# Permissões Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estou com o problemas com relação as permissões do usuário usando o Spring Security.
Cadastrei o usuário atribui a ele a permissão que lhe é devida, porém ao acessar o sistema a opção no menu que o usuário teria acesso não aparece.

Segue como está configurado o Spring Security no meu sistema:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    IUsuarioDAO usuarioDAO; 

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(usuarioDAO)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/vendas/cadastro-vendas").hasAnyRole("VENDAS_MERCADO")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/index").permitAll()
        .failureUrl("/index?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll()
        .and().rememberMe().userDetailsService(usuarioDAO)
        .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }   
}
```

Minha Entidade do Usuário:

```
package br.com.mercadinhojt.mercado.models;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class UsuarioDetails implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nome;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private boolean ativo;
    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> permissoes = new ArrayList<>();

    public UsuarioDetails(String nome, String login, String senha, boolean ativo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return permissoes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.senha;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.ativo;
    }

}
```

Minha Classe DAO

```
public class UsuarioDAOImpl implements IUsuarioDAO, UserDetailsService{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDetails.class.getSimpleName());


    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  
    private Connection connection;
    private CallableStatement cs;
    private ResultSet rs;

    @Autowired
    public UsuarioDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }   


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UsuarioDetails userDetails = null;
        try {           
            connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

            userDetails = buscarUsuario(connection, username);

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> permissoesPorUsuario = buscarPermissoes(connection,username);

            userDetails.getAuthorities().addAll(permissoesPorUsuario);          

            return userDetails;

        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                connection.close();
                cs.close();
                rs.close();     
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }       
        return userDetails;
    }

    public UsuarioDetails buscarUsuario(Connection connection, String login) throws SQLException {
        cs = this.connection.prepareCall("{call MEJT_SP_SEL_USUARIOS(?,?)}");
        cs.setString("MODO", "BUSCAR_USUARIO");
        cs.setString("LOGIN_USER", login);

        rs = cs.executeQuery();

        String nome = null;
        String senha = null;
        boolean ativo = false;

        while(rs.next()){               
            nome = rs.getString("NOME");
            senha  = rs.getString("SENHA");
            ativo = rs.getBoolean("ATIVO");             
        }

        rs.close();
        cs.close();

        return new UsuarioDetails(nome, login, senha, ativo);
    }

    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> buscarPermissoes(Connection connection, String login) throws SQLException {
        List<GrantedAuthority> permissoes = new ArrayList<>();

        cs = this.connection.prepareCall("{call MEJT_SP_SEL_USUARIOS(?,?)}");
        cs.setString("MODO", "ACESSAR_APLICACAO");
        cs.setString("LOGIN_USER", login);

        rs = cs.executeQuery();     

        while (rs.next()) {
            permissoes.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rs.getString("NMFORMULARIO")));
        }

        rs.close();
        cs.close();

        return permissoes;
    }
}
```

No caso **NMFORMULARIO** seria o nome da minha **ROLE**.
Quando o usuário faz o Login no sistema eu pego os dados do Usuário e depois pego todas as permissões que esse usuário tem acesso.

Debugando o sistema o método **buscarPermissoes()** está pegando corretamente a permissão que o usuário possui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu Header da JSP estou deixando dessa forma o menu (Especificamente o acesso que essa role permite):

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('VENDAS_MERCADO')">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="${s:mvcUrl('VC#vendasCaixa').build()}">Caixa</a>
    </li>
</sec:authorize>
```

Para montar essa regra usei como base uma aula da AlgaWorks, porém utilizavam spring bot.
Porem da forma que montei é muito parecido com o que eles estavam ensinando, porem não está funcionando. Quando acesso a minha aplicação esse item do menu não fica disponível para o usuário.
Essa aplicação que estou criando é o meu projeto de TCC e essa questão de atribuições de cada usuário seria um dos fundamentos da minha aplicação e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar essa regra de acesso. E também não queria que todos os usuários cadastrados no sistema tivessem acesso a tudo da aplicação.

Gostaria de saber se tem algo de errado no na hora de reconhecer a permissão que o usuário possui.

Se puderem contribuir agradeceria muito, só está faltando isso para concluir meu projeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já perdi muito tempo tentando resolver esse problema. Espero que seja o mesmo que passei.

Seguinte, você tem duas opções:

**1° - Dizer para o Spring ignorar o prefixo ROLE_.**

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.expressionHandler(new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        @Override
        protected SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
            WebSecurityExpressionRoot root = (WebSecurityExpressionRoot) super.createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
            root.setDefaultRolePrefix(""); //remove the prefix ROLE_
            return root;
        }
    });
}
```

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134121/how-do-i-remove-the-role-prefix-from-spring-security-with-javaconfig

**2° - Adicionar ROLE_ como prefixo nas suas permissões.**

```
public static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

public String getRole() {
    return ROLE_PREFIX + this.nomePermissao;
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado!! Era justamente esse o problema por conta da "ROLE_" que não tinha. Adicionei essa parte no nome da permissão que está no banco de dados e funcionou. Sensacional cara, valeu mesmo ajudou muito.!!!!

Comment: Opa, show de bola! Depois marca a questão como correta. Valeu, abraço!